# Check how many file descriptors are open on a file? (BSD, OSx)

Tags: c, macos, bsd

How can a process interrogate the system, to see if a device (file) has been opened and left hanging?

Context: I'm having trouble setting attributes (tcsetattr) on a FTDI serial interface device, and, amongst other things, I'm wondering if there are any hanging file descriptors, preventing the process from getting the kind of lock it wants before changing attributes.  If it *is* causing a problem, I also have a need to detect the problem and report it to the user (the code is susceptible to file-handle leaks).

It appears that the device can be opened multiple times (a shared mode) without error: I haven't advanced to the stage of trying to read or write to a device in that condition, because I haven't got past tcsetattr() yet.

Comment: On many systems there's a `lsof` (list open files) command that may help you.

Comment: ubuntu: ls /proc/self/fd | wc